# Data Explorer is down

Tags: support, status-completed, data-explorer

I can't create or run queries on the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/89/), I'm getting an ASP.NET yellow screen of death.
Please bring it back so that I may fulfill my statistical needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's back up, I'm still tracking down the exact cause that resulted in this, but it's available for use now.

*Update:* We're now comfortable this was resolved - it was a problem that simply showed no symptoms until the web site recycled last night (normal behavior).  Due to the way an app domain caches SQL instance references, you only need to resolve them on startup...so we didn't see errors until that was recycled, it's all better now :)

Comment: Is it related to the use of **non-enterprise** SSDs? `:P`

Comment: @jjnguy - I just found the cause, it was the upgrade yes, but nothing hardware related, just a mis-ordering in service startup that didn't matter really until the SEDE app pool recycled last night.  It shouldn't happen again, we'll note the change if/when we do an outage on that database server in the future.