# Is there any way to view comment flags in the Data Explorer?

Tags: support, comments, flags, data-explorer

Using the Data Explorer (SEDE), is there any way to view the flags on individual comments?

After reading [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678), it appears there is plenty of information in the tables `FlagTypes`, `PendingFlags`, etc., but nothing related to comments.

Comment: If it was available for what purpose would you want to query those flags?

Comment: Simple curiosity. It's nice to know how things work. Besides, I have [statistical needs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79625/data-explorer-is-down) that must be filled.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, flags are not available in Data Explorer because flags are generally considered private between the user and moderators. The PendingFlags table you actually have access to in Data Explorer *only* contains flags with TypeId of 13, 14, and 15 (which correspond to Recommend Closure Flags, Close Votes, and Reopen Votes respectively) and only those flags which are *still pending* (so any flag of those types that's ever been handled will not be there). No other flag information is provided outside of the very limited set identified.